# javascript Image Filters do not work in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a small filter photos , I found a few ready-made solutions , and not one of them is not working in chrome. for example, I downloaded from git hub [ready solution](https://github.com/alexmic/filtrr) that the user, running in chrome and it does not work , why?

Code which do not work

```
    <img src="megan_fox.jpg"/>
    <img id="img" src="megan_fox.jpg"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Filtrr2("#img", function() {                
            this.expose(10).render();
        });
    </script>
```

[this](https://github.com/mezzoblue/PaintbrushJS) do not work too

Comment: Do you have everything imported in the head of the HTML?

Comment: @AwesomeByte yes, https://github.com/alexmic/filtrr Download this example and try it in Google Chrome 45 without changing its